# Excel VBA: ComboBox Run-time error 6: Overflow when entering a key value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm building a procedure to get the selected value of a ComboBox in Excel VBA.

The code below works fine when the user picks the value with the mouse.
But when he types a key directly with the keyboard, I get the error:

```
Run-time error 6: Overflow
```

This is the code, the error is on the last line:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxCAE_Change()
Dim selecionado As Integer

'On Error Resume Next
selecionado = ComboBoxCAE.Value
```

I tried other event listners like AfterUpdate but nothing happens (the event isn't triggered).

Any help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Run-time error 6: Overflow` Generally means that the value is greater than the limit for an integer data type (-32,768 to 32,767). Try declaring `selecionado` as the data type long like so:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxCAE_Change()
Dim selecionado As Long

'On Error Resume Next
selecionado = ComboBoxCAE.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ComboBoxCAE.Value` must be lower/higher than the supported minimum/maximum value for an integer (see [this page](http://spreadsheetsuperstar.com/vba-integer-variable-data-type/), for example) which is -32,768 to 32,767.  Try changing `Dim selecionado As Integer` to `Dim selecionado As Long`; a [Long data type](http://spreadsheetsuperstar.com/vba-long-variable-data-type/) has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.